# Lower bound for $\vert \det A \vert $ for the adjacency matrix of regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, regular-graph

Assume $G$ is a simple $k$-regular graph of order $n$ with adjacency matrix $A$ which is non-singular.

Does anyone know some lower bounds for $\vert \det (A) \vert$ with respect to $n$, $k$ or both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of lower bounds you're looking for here.  Except for very extreme values of $k$ and $n$ it's easy to construct a graph where two vertices have identical neighborhoods.  $A$ would then have equal rows, so zero determinant.

Comment: You are right. Sorry I forgot to say $A$ is non-singular. Now, the question is modified.

Comment: Experimentally, it seems that $k$ is a lower bound.  Possibly the matrix tree theorem could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$k$ is a lower bound, since $k$ is an eigenvalue and the product of other eigenvalues is integer (they are roots of the monic polynomial with integer coefficients). I doubt that it may be improved without further assumptions.